# Access to sql server synchronisation

Tags: synchronization, sql-server, microsoft-access

I have a legacy VB system that creates a new access database for every job in our system, for example 1.Mdb, 2.mdb, 3.mdb I want to automatically write the details from these databases to a ms sql server. With multiple tables.

Changing the code in the legacy system is not possible and doing something manually in each access database is not possible with the number of databases. So I’m looking for ideas on how I can sync this to sql server on each change/creation of access databases.

Ideally I would like a way to sync back as well so going forward if we changed the data in sql server this would automatically update the relevant access database as if the job is re-opened in the legacy system it would need the most up to date information.

I am used to working with sql server so any suggestions on this can be achieved through sql would be great or any third party applications that could do the job. Hoping for a result of an automatic 2 way synchronisation.